# How to limit the characters in the result of azure cognitive search

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-cognitive-search

I am using azure cognitive search and the search is applied on content which is huge. It searches the result correctly but we don't need the entire content. How can we get just 2-3 rows of the content with the matching string. Basically i don't want the full content but just few characters(50-100) around the matching searched string.

Need to understand if this feature is available?

Comment: it would be great if you provide what you have tried through images or code

Answer (score 0):

The index will return what's on your fields. You can limit using a simple .Substring method either on front-end or back-end.

Comment: I think this won't work correctly if user tries to search with regex, operators or special chars

Comment: there's no relationship of the type of the search with the length of the result. He wants to limit the characters in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hit highlighting feature in Azure Search. Please see more information in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout#hit-highlighting).

Azure Search returns up to five text fragments, which are usually sentences, that contains the search hits per field. It currently does not allow you to configure the size of the window/fragment so you can't get a specific number of words surrounding the search terms.